# Remove property from CSS rule in a stylesheet I don't have direct access to

Tags: css

I am using a stylesheet in my code to stylize proprietary widgets, therefore I don't have access to alter the base stylesheet (nor is that really good practice anyway). One of the styles is causing problems in my application and I determined that the `margin: 0` property needs to be removed entirely from this CSS rule:

```
.esriBasemapGallerySelectedNode .esriBasemapGalleryThumbnail {
      border: 2px solid #F99;
      margin: 0;
}
```

Is there a way to do this? Since I cannot view the stylesheet in a formatted way, I cannot get the index of this rule. The styles aren't in-line so I don't think I can use the .css() method. If I can't remove it, the only alternative I can think of is setting it to 1px (which I tested and it removed the problem that's occurring) but I'm not a big fan of that solution.

Comment: `but I'm not a big fan of that solution.` --> this will be your only solution, override it

Comment: @Temani Afif - bummer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to expand the specificity of your element if you do not wish to override css rules. The easiest way to do this is to add an id on an element and then write a css rule for that element using the id instead of the classes.

Read more here:

https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: he was already able to override it. As you can read in the question `the only alternative I can think of is setting it to 1px (which I tested and it removed the problem that's occurring)`

Comment: @Adam S Thanks, I know how to override it but it's not my goal to do that. My goal is to remove the property altogether but it sounds like that's not possible given the constraints I have to work with.